# `rx` form, that is partially compiled, partially variable?

Tags: byte-compilation, rx

Is it possible to obtain an `(rx ...)` form, that is expanded at compile time for performance, but partially variable?

---

### `rx-to-string` may be slow

For instance I want an expression that behaves equivalent to

```
(rx-to-string `(: "PREFIX" 
                  (or "hello" "world" ,@user-defined-words)
                  "SUFFIX))
```

Written this way, it works, but does an unnecessary amount of work at runtime (especially in more complex real-world examples). In some places, this can become a potential performance issue.

What I want to produce at compile time is essentially a partial compile-time expansion, such as

```
(concat "PREFIX\\(?:hello\\|world\\|"
        (mapconcat #'regexp-quote user-defined-words "\\|")
        "\\)SUFFIX")
```

---

### `eval` form does not work

I already know that the `(rx ... (eval ...) ...)` form does not work:

```
;; INCORRECT RESULT; VARIABLE EXPANDED AT COMPILE TIME:
(rx "PREFIX" 
    (eval `(or "hello" "world" ,@user-defined-words)
    "SUFFIX))

;; When loading from source and user-defined-words is initialized to nil:
=> "PREFIX\\(?:hello\\|world\\)SUFFIX"

;; When compiling:
=> Error: Symbol's value as variable is void: user-defined-words
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Emacs 27, `rx` supports this via the following forms:

```
(literal EXPR) Match the literal string from evaluating EXPR at run time.

(regexp EXPR)  Match the string regexp from evaluating EXPR at run time.
```

n.b. The `regexp` form in earlier versions of rx is less flexible, and only accepts a string argument.

Answer (score 0):

A compiled regexp is just a string, so (a) no, I don't believe you can make any kind of dynamic substitution when the regexp engine processes it; but (b) you *can* search and replace on it yourself -- simply produce a regexp string containing token substrings which you *know* will not otherwise occur, and ensure they occur in a context which will be safe to replace.

```el
(rx "PREFIX" (or "hello" "world" (regexp "INFIX")) "SUFFIX")

=> "PREFIX\\(?:hello\\|world\\|INFIX\\)SUFFIX"
```

If you know that `PREFIX` and `INFIX` and `SUFFIX` are all unique in the regexp, then a simple run-time replacement of those can produce your desired outcome.

*Knowing* that your placeholders are unique and replaceable is the part you need to be careful about, so you might take advantage of the fact that the rx form `(regexp FOO)` trusts that `FOO` is a valid regexp string, and instead use it to produce an *invalid* regexp as a placeholder value -- therefore being safe in the knowledge that rx is never going to produce that same value<sup>1</sup>.

For example, if you searched for `(rx (regexp "[[:placeholder:]]"))` the regexp engine would signal `(invalid-regexp "Invalid character class name")`.

You could therefore do something like this:

```el
(defvar my-pattern-template
  (rx (group (or "hello" "world" (regexp "[[:placeholder:]]"))))
  "Regexp template with placeholder.")

;; Runtime...
(let* ((prefix "PREFIX")
       (suffix "SUFFIX")
       (words '("this" "is" "the" "word" "list" "to" "look" "for"))
       (regexp1 (progn
                  (string-match (rx "[[:placeholder:]]") my-pattern-template)
                  (replace-match (regexp-opt words) nil t my-pattern-template)))
       (regexp (concat (regexp-quote prefix)
                       regexp1
                       (regexp-quote suffix))))
  (re-search-forward regexp))
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `"\\[[:placeholder:]]"` is a *valid* regexp containing that placeholder -- equivalent to `"\\[[:placehodr]]"` and matching the text `[:]` for instance -- but `rx` shouldn't ever generate such unnecessary duplication of characters, so it's probably still safe; but these things *are* tricky, and my scheme might yet be flawed, so be suitably careful.  In practice, unless the inputs are *truly* arbitrary, you probably have enough control to provide certainty.

Comment: Regarding that footnote, `[[[:placeholder:]]]` may be better, in that it eliminates that particular way of unwanted matching, as `\\[[[:placeholder:]]]` is still invalid.

Comment: There is nothing really preventing the `rx' macro from expanding into a `(concat ...)` expression, so compilation of the rx-form doesn't preclude leaving parts of it variable. With the replacement method I am ensure; It results in worse readability compared to using the well-understood `rx`-macro, and I'm not sure it would be much faster than using `rx-to-string'.

Comment: My suggestion is certainly considerably less readable than `rx` or `rx-to-string`; but neither of them do what you want, so that seems fairly moot?  As for performance, you talked about "more complex real-world examples" which "can become a potential performance issue", so I'm presuming you have some case in mind where `rx-to-string` was particularly slow. If you don't have such a scenario in mind, I would just use that.

Comment: You'll be happy to learn that the re-written rx.el in Emacs 27 supports what you want.  I'll add a different answer.